# Set default color theme in vim under tmux/cygwin the same as outside tmux

Tags: vim, cygwin, tmux

I'm using tmux on Cygwin. When I open vim in Cygwin (without tmux), comments that start with `#` looks good:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXQ55.png)

But I open vim under tmux the same comments looks hard to read:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/marJB.png)

My `.bashrc` and `.vimrc`files are empty with default settings.

`.tmux.conf` contains only some simple commands:

```
#Change default prefix key
unbind-key C-b
set -g prefix 'C-\'
bind-key 'C-\' send-prefix

#Increase history limits
set-option -g history-limit 99999

#Start windows at 1, not 0
set -g base-index 1
setw -g pane-base-index 1

#Highlight border of active split pane with blue
set-option -g pane-active-border-fg blue

#Setting 256 colors globally in tmux
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"

#Colors of windows names
set-window-option -g window-status-current-fg colour33 #orange
set-window-option -g window-status-current-bg default
set-window-option -g window-status-current-attr bright

#Color of the task bar
set-option -g status-bg colour235 #base02
set-option -g status-fg colour136 #yellow
set-option -g status-attr default
```

How can I set up the color in vim to look under tmux the same as outside tmux?

Comment: Have you tried `:set background=light` in tmux/vim? to me, it looks like its a background light/dark setting, but it could also be `:set t_Co=256`
also make sure your terminal has support for 256 colors (`export TERM='xterm-256color'`)

Comment: @enrm, I set both settings in .vimrc, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my answer. This setting: `set background=dark` makes comments in vim to look the same both inside and outside tmux. Tested in Cygwin and in Ubuntu.